# Trouble with checked() for array of multiple checkboxes

Tags: php, forms, array

I can't get the checked() to return what I expect.

Data:

```
Options:  = array (
'baseball' => 'Baseball',
'golf' => 'Golf',
'hockey' => 'Hockey',
)

Values:  = array (
'baseball' => 'Baseball',
'golf' => '',
'hockey' => '',
)
```

I'm using this code to try to return 'checked="checked"'

```
foreach ( $options as $key => $title ) {
    rpq_plugin_debug_var( $key, 'Key: ' );
    rpq_plugin_debug_var( $title, 'Title: ' );
    $checked = checked((in_array($key, $values)), true, false);
```

I'd expect the baseball option to return 'checked="checked"' but it returns ''.

I've also tried this, which actually makes more sense to me, with no success, either.

```
$checked = checked((in_array($title, $values)), true, false);
```

Where is my error?

Many thanks.

EDIT: See comments below this post for answer.

1. Make $values array not associative.

   ```
      Values:  = array (
   'baseball',
   'golf'

   )
   ```
2. Use this line to identify checkmarks

   ```
   $checked = checked((in_array($key, $values)), true, false);
   ```

Comment: I don't think you can use `in_array` with associate arrays (not completely sure though). What if you try `$checked = checked((in_array($key, array_keys($values))), true, false);`

Comment: @czerspalace Thanks for the idea. That adds checkmarks to all the options, I guess because $key is always in array_keys().

Comment: Ahh, then maybe `$checked = checked((in_array($title, array_values($values))), true, false);`

Comment: @czerspalace Thanks. You pointed me in the right direction. My values array needed to not be associative, but to just have the keys from my options array.  Then I can use: `$checked = checked((in_array($key, $values)), true, false);`

Answer (score 0):

Why take empty answer

```
foreach ( $options as $key => $title ) {
      rpq_plugin_debug_var( $key, 'Key: ' );
      rpq_plugin_debug_var( $title, 'Title: ' );
      $checked = checked((in_array($title, $values)), true, false);
```

After this loop end you get empty $checked because it replace every loop step.

Trace:

```
1: $checked = 'checked="checked"'
2: $checked = '';
3: $checked = '';
```

After loop $checked = '';

So need return array for answers for multiply array like:
$checked[$key] = checked((in_array($title, $values)), true, false);

So you got answer:

```
$checked = array (
'baseball' => 'checked="checked"',
'golf' => '',
'hockey' => '',
)
```

And then use where it need.

Comment: Could you explain why this would solve OP's problem?

Comment: Code only answers are usually frowned upon, could you please [edit your question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/posts/272523/edit) and explain why this code would work?